# Why is my RabbitMQ queue consuming only sometimes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, rabbitmq

I am making my first microservices app (a wonky social media) and I'm trying to create a nice flow with my RabbitMQ's Message Broker, the idea is that when a user is Created, Updated or Deleted, a message will be put in a queue inside the message broker informing the other services to do their thing.

I successfully managed to implement it, or so I thought, apparently, although the flow works perfectly every single time when I make a request with Postman, once I started the implementation on my Frontend it just broke.

I did a lot of logging and I could not find anything with it, the request from the frontend leaves correctly, my first microservice (poster) handles it perfectly and posts it in the Message Broker, the Message Broker receives it correctly, and then we have the issue, sometimes the second service (receiver) picks up the message and handles it, but most of the time it does not. I could not find any pattern for this, it just randomly works and randomly does not work.

Here you can see the key parts of the code, if any more is needed I will update:

```
//Frontend "warn the backend" code (works every time)

useEffect(() => {
    keycloak.onAuthSuccess = function() {
      console.log(keycloak.token)
      axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/api/usr/self/${keycloak.subject}`, {headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer ${keycloak.token}`}});
    }
  })
```

```
//First service queue and endpoint (seems to work every time)

var mqChannel;

amqp.connect("amqp://localhost", function (error0, conn) {
  if (error0) {
    throw error0;
  }
  conn.createChannel(function (error1, channel) {
    if (error1) {
      throw error1;
    }

    channel.assertQueue("actions", {
      durable: false,
    });

    mqChannel = channel;
  });
});

app.get("/api/usr/self/:id", (req, res) => {
  jwt.verify(
    req.headers.authorization.replace("Bearer ", ""),
    secret,
    { algorithms: ["RS256"] },
    function (err, decoded) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      connection.query(
        `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='${decoded.sub}'`,
        (err, row, fields) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          
          if (row.length == 0) {
            var msg = {
              type: "create",
              id: decoded.sub,
              name: decoded.email,
            };
            mqChannel.sendToQueue("actions", Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(msg)));

            connection.query(
              `INSERT INTO users (id, name, bio, birthdate) VALUES ('${
                decoded.sub
              }', '${decoded.email}', ${null}, ${null})`,
              (err, row, fields) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("we sent it bro")

                res.status(200).send();
              }
            );
          } else {
            res.status(200).send();
          }
        }
      );
    }
  );
});
```

```
//Service supposed to consume message and handle it (works only when it wants)

amqp.connect("amqp://localhost", function (error0, connection) {
  if (error0) {
    throw error0;
  }
  connection.createChannel(function (error1, channel) {
    if (error1) {
      throw error1;
    }

    channel.assertQueue("actions", {
      durable: false,
    });

    channel.consume(
      "actions",
      function (msg) {
        var operation = JSON.parse(msg.content);
        switch (operation.type) {
          case "create":
            client.db("friendbook-friends").collection("friends").insertOne({
              _id: operation.id,
              username: operation.name,
              friendlist: [],
            });
            break;
          case "update":
            client
              .db("friendbook-friends")
              .collection("friends")
              .updateOne(
                { _id: operation.id },
                { $set: { username: `${operation.name}` } }
              );
            break;
          case "delete":
            client
              .db("friendbook-friends")
              .collection("friends")
              .deleteOne({ _id: operation.id });

            client
              .db("friendbook-friends")
              .collection("friends")
              .updateMany({}, { $pull: { friendlist: operation.id } });

            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      },
      {
        noAck: true,
      }
    );
  });
});
```